# problemas com confirmDialog do JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf-2.2, xhtml, primefaces-3.5

Consegui implementar a exclusão de registro em uma página JSF, porém ao excluir o registro ele não pede a tela de confirmação, não consigo entender, porque não está funcionando, mas a linha de código que solicita a confirmação da exclusão está lá, observem a pagina;

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="titulo">Pesquisa Produto</ui:define>


    <ui:define name="corpo">

        <h:form id="frmPesquisaProduto">

            <h1>Novo Produto</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Pesquisa"
                        action="#{pesquisaProdutoBean.pesquisa}" update="@form" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/produto/cadastro/CadastroProduto" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel"
                style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
                <p:outputLabel value="Nome do Produto" for="nomep" />
                <p:inputText id="nomep" size="60" maxlength="90"
                    value="#{pesquisaProdutoBean.filtro.nome}" />
            </p:panelGrid>


            <p:dataTable id="produtosTable"
                value="#{pesquisaProdutoBean.produtosFiltrados}" var="produto"
                style="margin-top: 20px" emptyMessage="Nenhum produto encontrado."
                rows="20" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                paginatorPosition="bottom">
                <p:column headerText="Nome do Produto"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.nomeproduto}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Imagem do Produto">
                    <h:outputText value="a imagem será ainda implementada" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Valor do produto"
                    style="text-align: right; width: 120px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.valorproduto}">
                        <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Descrição do Produto"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.descproduto}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
                    <p:button outcome="/produto/cadastro/CadastroProduto"
                        icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar">
                        <f:param name="produto" value="#{produto.idproduto}" />
                    </p:button>


                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-closethick" title="Excluir"
                        process="@this" update=":frmPesquisaProduto:produtosTable"
                        action="#{pesquisaProdutoBean.excluir}">

                        <f:setPropertyActionListener
                            target="#{pesquisaProdutoBean.produtoSelecionado}"
                            value="#{produto}" />

                        <p:confirmDialog header="Confirmation"
                            message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto #{pesquisaProdutoBean.produtoSelecionado.nomeproduto} ?"
                            icon="ui-icon-alert" />

                    </p:commandButton>





                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>


            <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                <p:commandButton value="SIM" type="button"
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                <p:commandButton value="NÃO" type="button"
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
            </p:confirmDialog>



        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

O pedaço do código em questão é esse:

```
                <p:confirmDialog header="Confirmation"
                    message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto #{pesquisaProdutoBean.produtoSelecionado.nomeproduto} ?"
                    icon="ui-icon-alert" />
```

Isso acima era para funcionar, mas não está funcionando, existe outra maneira de implementar a tela de confirmação de exclusão?

Comment: Exibe alguma mensagem de erro? Se conseguir pegar o log do momento exato que clica para excluir, poste para ajudar.

Comment: tenta tirar o `process="@this"` do botão excluir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe sim, com exemplo no show case do Primefaces, é necessário a tag `confirm` dentro do `commandButton` do qual faz a chamada para a exclusão do item e logo abaixo dentro da tag `confirmDialog` precisa de dois `commandButton` para representar o **Sim** e **Não**

```
<h:form>           
    <p:commandButton value="Excluir" actionListener="#{pesquisaProdutoBean.excluir}" update="message">
        <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o produto #{pesquisaProdutoBean.produtoSelecionado.nomeproduto} ?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
        <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml

Comment: somente uma observação, esse p:confirm somente vai pegar dependendo da versão do primefaces, o mais adequado usar o mais novo.